# Problems with eigendecomposition of a big stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, matrix-decomposition, stochastic-matrices

I face the following problem. I generate a big $1202 \times 1202$ stochastic matrix $Q$ whose columns adds to $1$ (up to numeric precision). The elements of $Q$ are in $[0,1]$. I use the eigendecomposition

```
[ R, D ] = eig( Q )
```

and I compute

```
L = inv( R )
```

I have NO warning that R is close to singular and the elements of R may have big imaginary parts.
(I tried to use `[ R, D, L ] = eig( Q )`but R*L dose not provide an identity matrix).

I get a result where:

`Q ~= real( R*D*L )`

At the end I have better results in matlab just by using

`Q^200000` than `R*D^200000*L`.

Is there any explanation for this behavior?